# Different functions with the same integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

Given $\alpha<0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$,  let us consider the two integrals:

1. $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} e^{\alpha \|x\|^2}dx$
2. $\frac{2|\alpha|}{N}\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \|x\|^2e^{\alpha\|x\|^2}dx$.

I have proved that both of them are equal for $N=1,2,3$. But I don't know how to prove the equality in higher dimensions. Could someone help me?

Comment: Is $|x|$ supposed to represent $\Vert (x_1,...,x_n) \Vert$? If so, then $\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert$ would be more appropriate.

Comment: You're right. The notation is confused, I edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The angular parts don't matter, could you somehow prove that

$$N\int_0^\infty r^{N-1}e^{\alpha r^2}\:dr = -2\alpha\int_0^\infty r^{N+1}e^{\alpha r^2}\:dr$$

Comment: I agree, converting into $n$ dimensional spherical coords is probably a good idea for this problem.

Comment: Yes, I found them in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) but I don't know how to use them here, I obtain a complex expression.

Comment: @Loye94 again the angular integrals don't matter, they will evaluate to the same constant on both sides. This is a simple integration by parts.